# rotating annotation views

Tags: iphone

I am working on one Map application. I want to show the map on start of application with angle of rotation.

problem: My Problem is map is rotating with the angle provided but annotation view is also rotating. I don't want to rotate my annotation views.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the latitude and longitude in terms of X and Y then you can show your annotation view on that position.